# Image alignment issue with HTML5

Tags: css, image, grid

I have 3 images. 2 which are to float on the left, with the dimensions of 490x260 and one taller image to float on the right, which is 490x545. i want to have the 3 images floating side by side, so the two left ones on top of each other are the same height as the taller one to the right. Please help. Thank you

```
<div class="media-section">
            <div class="section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col6">
                            <div class="media-section__thumbnail thumbnail">
                                <a href=""><img src="imgs/florida_door.jpg">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></p></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col6">
                            <div class="media-section__thumbnail thumbnail">
                                <a href="#"><img src="imgs/book_now_door.jpg">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></p></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col6">
                            <div class="media-section__thumbnail  thumbnail">
                                <a href="sub_pages/las_salinas_spain.html"><img src="imgs/spain_door.jpg">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></p></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--row end-->
                </div><!--container end-->
            </div><!--section end-->
        </div><!--medi-section end-->
```

And the css

```
.section {
padding: 4rem 0 ;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
.media-section {
background: #ebebeb; 
overflow: hidden;
```

}

```
.container {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1000px;
```

}

```
.thumbnail img {
border: 2px solid #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #184450;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

}

```
.media-section__thumbnail p {
position: absolute;
bottom: 1%;
right: 8%;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, arial;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 600;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing: .4rem;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Have the first 2 images in the same col6 div
- Have the 3rd image in the second col6 div
- Remove the extra col6 div
- Float the col6

Also, to make the images stack in the first column, you should make them `display: block` and remove the `width` and `height` - they're not needed.

```
.col6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Give the first column an additional class of `first`

```
.col6.first img {
  display: block
}
```

Comment: thats working now cheers! only problem I have now is the text that is to go at the bottom to act as a link with the image.

        .thumbnail p {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 1%;
 right: 8%;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, arial;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #fff;
 letter-spacing: .4rem;
 text-align: center;
}


The text on the two left images are both showing on the bottom one

Comment: Because of `position: absolute`, I'd imagine. Remove that.

Comment: Its alright. I added position relative to its parent 'thumbnail' and its all sorted. cheers buddy!!!